# allow specific <script> tags in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, mathjax

I am using DotNetBlogEngine and to post math equations I'd like to use MathJax, a JS Component which makes it super simple to embed LaTeX code like this:

```
<script type="math/tex; mode=display">
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over n^2} = {\pi^2\over 6}
</script>
```

My problem is, as I put the HTML-Code in de Code-View of CKEditor save it an I reopen it it looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
      \sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over n^2} = {\pi^2\over 6}

// ]]></script>
```

I think this is for security reasons. Is there a way to allow script tags of type `math/tex` ?

Comment: Firstly, kudos for using MathJax - I'm a big fan of it. Secondly, why not (instead of making users write out script tags) use LaTeX-style delimiters (`$`) and replace them serverside with their HTML counterparts?

Comment: No, those `<![CDATA[]]>` blocks have nothing to do with the kind of security you're thinking about. Those are added, presumably, because it's an XHTML DOCTYPE (maybe due to the LaTeX?) and you have to mark `script` tag data as character data (`CDATA`) blocks so things like `>` and entities don't poke the parser between the eyes.

Comment: @JimO'Brien: Good mention, i didn't think about this possibility yet.

Comment: I agree, it doesn't have to be explicitly in `script` tags, as long as it's kept together. On another note, I saw a really good web-based math formula editor just a week or so ago...

Comment: @JaredFarrish: I'm not shure if I understand your first comment. That it isn't for sec seems clear. Do you mean I schould embed the latex inside the CDATA tag? But anyway the type attribute get's replaced.

Comment: Well, you say in your question you think it's for security reasons (which is what I was responding to). It's not, it's just a factor of using XHTML, unless you mean the alternate `math/tex` removal is a security issues; it's not either. I know in TinyMCE it has a method for granting tag and attribute validity in output. I assume CKEditor has the same functionality.

Comment: And yes, if you're using an [XHTML DOCTYPE](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#normative) in your content editing and delivery, you have to keep the `CDATA` blocks, it's part of the well-formedness rule of XML. If you don't need it (you may not), you could possibly tell CKEditor to use HTML5 instead (`<!doctype html><html lang="en">`) and you wouldn't have to bother with the `CDATA` wrappers.

Comment: @john84 - I made some edits. I'm still not sure what's going on with the `type` tag, although I want to investigate the editor munging it (since I don't know that the one you're using is "valid" in the context of XHTML, it's real picky about some things). Also, BBCode output could possibly work.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested the sample code in the demo at http://ckeditor.com/demo and I don't see any change to the contents or the attributes of the script.

I've tested Firefox, Chrome and IE9.

Are you sure that the problem is CKEditor and not something on your server, or some plugin that you have added?

Comment: It is a plugin, it's the MathJax plugin.

Comment: Shame on me! Dot Net Blog Engine doesn't use CKEditor, instead it uses TinyMCE. I could cry hours I spent with the wrong documentation. Anyway even on the TinyMCE Demo the type get's not replaced, I'll take a look on the server side

Comment: @john84 - What?!?! I knew TinyMCE had an editor, because I saw it last week... Sigh.

Answer (score 1):

Well the solution.

1. after a second look on the MathJax Documentation I found out that I can embed Math using the `script`-Tag as in my Question but also using the Latex Math-Block notation `\[\]`. For example:

   \[x_{1,2} = \left(\frac{p}{2} \right) \pm \sqrt{\left(\frac{p}{2}\right)^2 - q} \]

it works.

1. It would have been possible to use a WSIWYG-Editor Plugin (like that wiris.com/portal/plugins/demo/tinymce/aspx ) the probelm, these plugins generate png pictures and reference them. They have less quality than MathJax.